# AFNetworking post JSON string

Tags: php, ios, json, afnetworking

I was trying to post JSON string to php. I have created JSON as

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arr addObject:@{@"step1":[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@{@"key1":@"value1"}, @{@"key2":@"value2"}, @{@"key3":@"value3"}, nil]}];
     [arr addObject:@{@"step2":[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@{@"key1":@"value1"}, @{@"key2":@"value2"}, @{@"key3":@"value3"}, nil]}];
    jsonString = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSLog(@"JSON %@",jsonString);
```

It prints json as

```
JSON (
        {
        step1 =         (
                        {
                key1 = value1;
            },
                        {
                key2 = value2;
            },
                        {
                key3 = value3;
            }
        );
    },
        {
        step2 =         (
                        {
                key1 = value1;
            },
                        {
                key2 = value2;
            },
                        {
                key3 = value3;
            }
        );
    }
)
```

I am making a request to send json string as follows

```
 NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"2", @"userid",jsonString , @"totaldata", nil];
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    NSLog(@"Requesting..");
    [client postPath:@"" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response){
        NSLog(@"AFN response %@", operation.responseString);
        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *responseData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
        complete(responseData);
    }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         NSDictionary *nsDError = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:error.description, @"error", nil];
         failure(nsDError);
     }];
}
```

When I print it from php, 
I get response as

```
{"json":[{"step1":[{"key1":"value1"}]},{"step1":[{"key2":"value2"}]},{"step1":[{"key3":"value3"}]},{"step2":[{"key1":"value1"}]},{"step2":[{"key2":"value2"}]},{"step2":[{"key3":"value3"}]}]}
```

My php script,

```
$totaldata = $_POST["totaldata"];
$response = array("json"=>$totaldata);        
 $this->response($response,200);
```

In php, I was just printing json string in response to the json request.
I am expecting json to be equal in request and response, but in response, json varies with requested json string.
Can any one help me in this aspect?

Comment: You don't say what the difference is.  And, make the JSON as small as possible, while still having the problem.  Don't expect people to do this work for you.

Comment: Also, that's not JSON. (So what format is it actually in?)

Comment: I want to create json string as [{"step1":[{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"},{"key3":"value3"}]},{"step2":[{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"},{"key3":"value3"}]}]. For that, I have written

Comment: NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arr addObject:@{@"step1":[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@{@"key1":@"value1"}, @{@"key2":@"value2"}, @{@"key3":@"value3"}, nil]}];
     [arr addObject:@{@"step2":[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@{@"key1":@"value1"}, @{@"key2":@"value2"}, @{@"key3":@"value3"}, nil]}];
    jsonString = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I got the problem. Problem is with converting NSData to NSString. I need to create jsonString from NSData by  NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];